# FreeRTOS interlock with two buttons

Tags: c, mutex, semaphore, esp8266, freertos

I am trying to make sure that when button1 triggers a task, button2 is not able to trigger its task.

I am using this code, does it do the job? what happens if the two interrupts fire simultaneously?

```
void button1_callback(uint8_t gpio_num, button_event_t event) {
    if (up_task_handle == NULL && down_task_handle == NULL) {
        xTaskCreate(button1_task, "UP Task", 128, NULL, 2, up_task_handle);
    }
}

void button2_callback(uint8_t gpio_num, button_event_t event) {
if (up_task_handle == NULL && down_task_handle == NULL) {
    xTaskCreate(button2_task, "DOWN Task", 128, NULL, 2, down_task_handle);
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: What calls the callbacks?   Thread? Interrupt-handler direct?

Comment: _I am trying to make sure that when button1 triggers a task, button2 is not able to trigger its task._ and _I am using this code, does it do the job? what happens if the two interrupts fire simultaneously?_.  These are questions you should be able to determine the answers to yourself.  Run the code.  Debug it.

Comment: TO:James Interrupt handlers call the button callbacks. TO:ryyker I cannot create a race condition on demand.

Comment: @ageorgios: I think it is possible that a race condition can occure. You have to look what's happening inside the taskcreate. I think this function is not attomic. But it depends on the implementation. It's possile that FreeRTOS disables all ISRs after function call. You could think about using a mutex (in FreeRTOS: SemaphoreHandle_t xSemaphoreCreateBinary()).